# Saving or updating ParseUser in cloud code

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am getting the error response as "**user objects cannot allow writes from other users**" when trying to signUp or update a ParseUser in cloud code. 
As specified by the Parse team I am using Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey() so that I can bypass the restrictions.
Where possibly am I going wrong? I am confused as this code was previously working.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible, can you provide some codes related with your problem? For example below code is updating the Parse User name column successfully (tested on Parse cloud);

```
   Parse.Cloud.define("test", function(request, response) {
   Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
   var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
   query.equalTo("objectId", request.params.objectId);
   query.first({
      success: function(object) {
         object.set("name", request.params.name);
         object.save();
         response.success("Success Message");
      },
      error: function(error) {
         response.error("Error Message");
      }
   });
});
```

However, if one of the ParseUser tries to update another then it is highly possible the problem is related with the ACL. If you provide codes, it is really helpful. Hope this helps,

Regards.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the comment. In my case a Parse user is trying to update another Parse User. But as per their documentation I am using Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey() which ignores all the ACLs while doing so. I am still not understanding the issue.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); has been deprecated in Parse Server version 2.3.0 (Dec 7, 2016). From that version on, it is a no-op (it does nothing). You should now insert the {useMasterKey:true} optional parameter to each of the methods that need to override the ACL or CLP in your code.